# Decode JSON cURL response to Laravel Table

Tags: json, laravel, api, curl

I have a cURL GET request which returns the following response in JSON format:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "transaction": "LstByNumber",
        "records": [
            {
                "CUNM": "100",
                "CUCL": "FR",
                "CUNO": "000000",
                "CFC3": "RET",
                "PONO": "90",
                "EDE2": "GBY",
                
            },
```

In Laravel, my "m3customs" database contains fields with names that match the fields under "records" in the JSON response. Migration looks something like this:

```
    {
        Schema::create('m3customs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('CUNM')->nullable();
            $table->string('CUCL')->nullable();
            $table->string('CUNO')->nullable();
            $table->string('CFC3')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I have a controller to run the CURL request and send the information to Laravel "m3Customs" database above, but fails to update:

```
// Send request Laravel
    DB::table('m3customs')->delete();
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $data = json_decode($response,true);
    foreach ($data['records'] as $obj) {
        m3customs::create(array(
            'CUNM' => $obj->CUNM,
            'CUCL' => $obj->CUCL,
            'CUNO' => $obj->CUNO,
            'CFC3' => $obj->CFC3
        ));
```

I keep getting some type of error along the lines of:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null...

If I modify the following line `$data = json_decode($response,true);` and change to:

```
$data = json_decode($response['records'],true);
```

I get:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

I also tried modifying the `foreach ($data['records'] as $obj),` in which case, Laravel returned the following error:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null

I have updated, downgraded PHP and cleared the config cache.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you pass `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode()`, your result will be an array. So you can't access it with `$obj->CUNM`.

Comment: Isn't it `$response['results'][0]['records']` instead of `$response['records']`?

Comment: `$data ['results']['records']`  you try this way

Comment: Check this option https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#refsect1-function.curl-exec-returnvalues

Comment: @shaedrich: `$data = json_decode($response['results'][0]['records']);` returns the following error: "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool"

Comment: Try `$data = json_decode($response)['results'][0]['records'];`